# How to handle contract violations when using NUnit

Tags: c#, .net, nunit, nunit-3.0

When running the following test (using nunit-3.2) with NUnit3 test adapter in VS Community edition:

```
class TestClass
{
    [Test]
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        Contract.Assert(false);
    }
}
```

it simply freezes. Normally if it happens during normal application run - there is a popup with options whether to fail or ignore the violation.

But if it happens in the tested code - how would one handle the case and fail the test (as it would fail if it was an unhandled exception)?

Comment: Look at the [remarks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412879(v=vs.110).aspx): "Optionally, the analyzer can be instructed to throw an exception"

Comment: @JeroenHeier yep, I just found that you use `CodeContractsRuntimeThrowOnFailure` for that, now the question is how to set it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to install the [Code Contracts for .NET](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1ec7db13-3363-46c9-851f-1ce455f66970) extension. In its parameters you can select whether to throw an exception or not.